# Is it legal to charge interest on interest?

Tags: interest

I bought a mobile home through a private deal, financed by the owner. The last payment of a thousand dollars was an interest payment.

Due to financial problems, I could not give them the whole thousand dollars, but I gave them what I could, and they started charging me 10% interest on the balance.

My question is that since the last payment of a thousand dollars was interest, can they charge interest on that?

Comment: Yes, its called compound interest.  Unless there is a specific law local to you forbidding or limiting it.

Comment: +1 yes, you can be charged for any outstanding debt with a creditor, regardless of how it was generated, even interest balance, that's why even for "payoff" balance, they are guaranteed until the next interest cycle, usually about 10 days, give or take how the terms are setup, they will give a date up until which that payoff balance will be all you pay

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ, quid Answers to questions belong in the answer box, [not in the comments](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/10997).

Comment: Questions regarding the legality of something should include the country you are in (and probably the state as well if you are in the US) as laws can vary greatly between jurisdictions.

Comment: @BenMiller, I didn't consider that comment to be an answer.  I suppose I should have urged the person to update the question to include a locality and/or the correct terminology.  Or asked for locality rather than indicating that locality would impact the answer.

Comment: @quid The question was "Is it legal?", and you answered, "Yes."  :)

Comment: @BenMiller not sure what you are getting at but I am not responsible for where others put their answers. I commented on what was there and where it was, nothing more. Just to add context and expand on it, nothing more.

Comment: @DStanley agreed (+1) and that's why I felt that using comments was more appropriate than an answer because until the full picture is more clear, it was the extent of involvement that made sense. As for what the question needs to be better, I did that in the flag as part of the post review, so didn't see it was necessary to double down on it in the comment. Plus my response was mostly to the comment for reinforcement of the information, not directly to answer the question which was already addressed by someone, no need to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ If I misunderstood, I apologize.  I'm not sure what you upvoted or were commenting on, but it looks to me like you answered the question with a "yes."  If you were attempting to leave a comment for quid's "answer," then this example highlights one of the problems with answering a question in the comment section.

Comment: @BenMiller no apologies needed my friend, just letting you know why I took the approach I did, I am sorry if you took offense, the damn text medium leaves a lot to be desired in conveying intent :( I wasn't answering so much as affirming what quid had already said, hence the +1 to show this is affirmation of the comment preceding mine, nothing more. We're all good, no worries ;) The site's design leaves a lot to be desired and the rotating regimes means it will always remain inconsistent, SIGH, we do the best we can. I will own that I should have probably noted quid in my comment to make clear

Answer (score 4):

Yes it most cases it is legal. Plus depending on how you look at it, the last payment of 1000 can be principal paid and interest was paid in initial installments.